# Variable expansion in image and repo name

Tags: drone.io

Am using drone docker plugin to build and publish docker images, while building the docker image, i want refer some of the env variables exposed by Drone in drone docker plugin **repo** and **tags** parameters.

***What is needed***

- **repo** = first three characters of **DRONE_COMMIT_BRANCH** variable value - like ${DRONE_COMMIT_BRANCH:0:3}, **not working**
- **tags** = first seven characters of DRONE_COMMIT_SHA variable value, like ${DRONE_COMMIT_SHA:0:7}, **working**
- **image** = should be according to above repo and tags like,
  Eg:- image: registry/repo:tag
  image: registry/${DRONE_COMMIT_BRANCH:0:3}:${DRONE_COMMIT_SHA:0:7}

***Concerns***

- I can use any env variable exposed by Drone for such purpose, or only
  specific is only can be used?
- drone docker plugin **repo** parameter supports env variable
  expansion and string manipulation, as supported by **tags**
  parameter?
- image parameter support variable expansion and string manipulation?

**Drone YAML file**
[image]

Please suggest me how to achieve this use case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One more thing, drone is not returning any value if variable is having 3 characters, see the below explanation:

if DRONE_COMMIT_BRANCH=dev
${DRONE_COMMIT_BRANCH:0:3} - drone not returning any value, though variable expansion container is working fine with syntax $${DRONE_COMMIT_BRANCH:0:3}
${DRONE_COMMIT_BRANCH:0:2} - this is working

Comment: I wonder if the single quote has any effect on this have you tried without it?

Comment: Yes, i have already tried without single quotes, tags variable expansion is already working with quotes as well.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to do the same. Were you able to do this?